# Function with given properties in range $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm looking for a function with the following properties:

$$f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$$
$$f(0) = 1$$
$$f(1) = 0$$
$$f'(0) = -\infty$$
$$f'(1) = 0$$

It should look like the $\frac{1}{x}$ but with the given properties. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean $f'(0) = -\infty$? If $f'(0) = \infty$ and $f(0) = 1$, then the function will have a value not in $[0, 1]$

Answer (score 2):

Consider $$f(x) =1- \sqrt{x(2-x)}$$

Comment: perhaps worth saying that this is a quarter of a circle centred at $(1,1)$

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you want $f(0) = 1, f(1) = 0, f'(0) = +\infty, f'(1) = 0$ and $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$

- $f(x)= \sqrt x$ will give you $f'(0)=\infty$ but $f(0)=0$
- $f(x)= 1+\sqrt x$ will give you $f'(0)=\infty$ and $f(0)=1$ but $f(1)=2$
- $f(x)=(x-1)^2$ will give you $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$ and $f'(1)=0$ but $f'(0)=-2$
- $f(x)= (1+\sqrt x)(x-1)^2$ will give you $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$ and $f'(1)=0$ and $f'(0)=\infty$ and looks like

[image]

As Joshua Wang has commented, this cannot avoid exceeding $1$ near $x=0$ as you start at $f(0)=1$ with a positive derivative